# What Regex do I use to specify a number below 1000000?

Tags: regex

What would the best RegEx be for allowing the input of a number below 1000000 (1 million) with 2 decimal places? For example:

**Valid:**

- 1
- 1.10
- 999999.99 (maximum)
- 0.50

**Invalid**

- 1.5
- 1.
- 1000000

Essentially, a currency value below 1 million.

I've come up with the following, but it requires the decimal point and doesn't require a decimal value should the decimal point be added:

```
^[0-9]{1,6}\\.?[0-9]{0,2}$
```

Comment: `^\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` should work.

Comment: @Matt Why is "1" valid?\

Comment: Practically never use regex to achive this. Use operator capabilities of the programming language.

Comment: @Vishnudev this is to be used with https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask, and I've been given a very strict specification by the client that the user can't input an invalid value

Comment: Why use regex with input mask in the first place. Why not parseInt(value) < 1000000

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. `^(\d|[1-9]\d{1,5})(\.\d{2})?$` Matches any number below 1 million, with two optional decimal places. Will not match leading zeros.

https://regex101.com/r/Hz1b3G/1

If leading zeros are allowed, use this one `^0*\d{1,6}(\.\d{2})?$`

Answer (score 0):

I will echo the sentiment that you should check this using your programming language after the value has been entered.

A requirement like this could of course be satisfied by "1-6 digits optionally followed by a decimal point and two more digits," but in my opinion "a regular expression is not the appropriate way to do it" because soon-enough the business will come up with a twist on this requirement that will defeat this approach. When, not if, this happens, you'll regret having tried to do it this way.

Use the regex to ensure that the input IS "a number," but not to check the characteristics of that number.  Use if/then/else logic elsewhere in your application for this, and all other, data-validation rules.  "Less than 1 million" is simply another rule – one of many.